# How did the algo trading firms perform during Brexit?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

Brexit saw a lot of volatility in the market. Pound crashed to record lows and the market still seems recovering. Manual traders lost a lot of money. How did the Algos performed?

Comment: What kind of algo traders? Systematic macro? CTA? High frequency trading? Equity market neutral? Vol arb?

Comment: While it certainly is an interesting question, it's not really a good question for our format. I'd assume some algos made money and others lost some.

Comment: I was able to find a couple articles that discuss how some algo-focused players performed in the wake of Brexit. Mostly seems they fared reasonably well, all things considered. Here's some fodder from [The Street](https://www.thestreet.com/story/13623030/1/how-hedge-fund-algorithms-beat-human-rivals-in-post-brexit-trading.html), [Zero Hedge](http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2016-06-29/algos-are-winning-again-trading-brexit-chaos), and [WSJ](http://www.wsj.com/articles/in-brexit-trading-machine-beats-man-1467158146).